# Find out what object caused the hit test and compare position to character in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, collision-detection, hittest, flash-cc

I have been searching far and wide for this answer and I haven't found an answer to my question because my objects are not in an array, but in a movieclip on the stage.  I'm trying to detect which object caused the collision so that I use the objects to restrict the movement of the character.  Looking at the image below all of the bushes, the house, and a few dozen other objects are going to be used as blocking objects.

[image]

I have found a way to detect the collision with the movieclips children objects, but not really which object is making this collision.  I've tried looping through each object everytime a movement takes place, and testing if there was a collision, but it never registers any hits.

Here is my current code that is registering hits.

```
        var background = bGround; // Make reference to the BG in the mainActions 
        var bgObjects = bGround.bgElements; 

        //trace(bgObjects.numChildren); 

        if(bgObjects.hitTestPoint(character.x,character.y,true)) { 
            trace("character: " + character.x + "," + character.y);
            trace("position of hit " + bgObjects.x + "," + bgObjects.y);
        }
```

This is nested inside of a eventlistener that watches for key presses so it re-tests every button press, or every time the user moves the character.  I thought looping through the objects after the hit test happens was the best idea, or during each movement loop through and test that object in particular, but couldn't get either working.  Here is one attempt.

```
for (var i : Number = 0; i < bgObjects.numChildren; i++) { 
                    var instBgElem = bgObjects.getChildAt(i); 

                    if(character.hitTestPoint(instBgElem.x, instBgElem.y, true)) { 

                        // Check X Left
                        if (character.x < bgObjects.getChildAt(i)).x { 
                                trace("hit left"); 
                        }
                        // Check X right 
                        if ( character.x > bgObjects.getChildAt(i)).x { 
                                trace("hit right"); 
                        }
                        // Check Y top 
                        if ( character.y < bgObjects.getChildAt(i)).y { 
                                trace("hit top"); 
                        }
                        // Check Y Bottom
                        if ( character.y > bgObjects.getChildAt(i)).y { 
                                trace("hit bottom"); 
                        }

                    }
                }
```

**EDIT** : I was able to get one piece of code working to an extent, but it really doesn't test where the hit test occurs on the background object.  I may need to find the bounding box of each object and figure out which side of the bounding box is being hit, accepting all help here.

```
for (var i : Number = 0; i < bgObjects.numChildren; i++) { 
                 var instBgElem = bgObjects.getChildAt(i);
                 if(instBgElem.hitTestPoint(character.x,character.y,true)){
                     if(instBgElem.x > character.x) { 
                       trace("right"); 
                     } else if(instBgElem.x < character.x) { 
                       trace("left"); 
                     }
                     if(instBgElem.y > character.y) { 
                       trace("up"); 
                     } else if(instBgElem.y < character.y) { 
                       trace("down"); 
                     }
                 }
            }
```

**EDIT 2:** The problem is figuring out where the hit test comes in contact with the character so that I can restrict that movement.  I'm not sure how to do that, I have been experimenting with bounding box.

```
var charBounding = character.getBounds(this); 

        trace("character bounding box" + charBounding); 
        trace("character bottom: " + charBounding.bottom);
        trace("character top:" + charBounding.top); 
        trace("character left:" + charBounding.left); 
        trace("character right:" + charBounding.right);
```

That outputs character and updates it whenever the character moves, don't know how to use this to my advantage.

character bounding box(x=85.95, y=79.05, w=72.2, h=72.2)
character bottom: 151.25
character top:79.05
character left:85.95
character right:158.15

Comment: `if (character.x < bgObjects.getChildAt(i)).x {` - this won't work for sure - you have a typo. I didn't get the second part - you made it work, but not quite?! What's your real problem if it's getting a hit test? If it's because these are images and it hits on transparent places - let me know. Otherwise - describe better :)

Comment: Sure.  Sorry about the confusion.  Basically I have the hittest working, but my problem now has changed slightly to be where I can't tell where on the character the hit test is taking place.  If the hit test is taking place on the bottom of the characters bounding box then I need to tell the movement to stop, and not let the down key move the character anymore.  If the hit test is taking place on the left side of the character I can't let the character move left, and so on for right and top.

Comment: @AndreyPopov do the above descriptions help?